# Passing Data from View to Controller failed in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass data from view to controller but it always returns 0 and I don't know why.
I have to verify if the entred code is the same as passed in parametre of ActionResult Sortie() but I can't get the value entred in view.

**View:**

```
    @model ViewModel.DemandeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sortie";
}
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="box">
    <h2>Sortie Gabarit</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("Sortie", "Demandes", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodeBarre)

        @ViewBag.error
        @Html.ValidationMessage("error_msg")
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CodeBarre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeBarre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "codeB" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CodeBarre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Sortie" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    }
</div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  //Get Sortie
    public ActionResult Sortie(Int64 id)
    {
         TempData["codebarre"] = id;

        return View();

    }
    //Post Sortie
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Sortie()
    {

        var mvtrepository = new MvtRepository(db);
        var c = Request.Form["codeB"];

        if (Convert.ToInt64(TempData["codebarre"]) == Convert.ToInt64(c))
        {
            var mvtInsert = mvtrepository.InsertMvt(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt64(TempData["codebarre"]), 2);
            return RedirectToAction("Traitement");
        }


        else
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

Help please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not access the `Request.Form` directly. Instead, your POST action should accept the ViewModel as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sortie(ViewModel.DemandeViewModel postData) {
     int c = postData.CodeBarre; // assuming CodeBarre is an int in the ViewModel
     if ((int)TempData["codebarre"] == c) {
         // ...
     }
     // ...
}
```

Also in your View, let MVC set the `name` attribute so the ViewModel can be bound correctly by the ModelBinder.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CodeBarre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Because you have an Editor input for the CodeBarre, you do not need another hidden input for it. Remove the line

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CodeBarre)
```

Comment: Glad I could help you :)